# Class instance as class variable in python

Tags: python, class, class-variables

I am making a class which I would like to have as a *class* member of a separate class so that all instances of this second class can access the first class.  At the moment I have something which looks like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print "In Constructor!"

class B:
    ClassA = ''
    def __init__(self, InstanceA):
        self.ClassA = InstanceA
```

However, I get complaints saying "str object has no attribute..." when I try and use the `ClassA` class variable.  Is there a way to construct class `B` with an argument of `InstanceA` and then somehow set it to be a class variable? Or any other solution for that matter!

Comment: Although possible, this sounds like a really gnarly idea.

Comment: Surely having shared class members can be useful @wim?

Comment: Yes, that's what class attributes are for, but having that shared resource changing every time a new instance is initialised smells like a fishy design

Comment: What is above is only pseudocode.  In my actual program class A is actually an interface to another much bigger class that I want all instances of class B to be able to interface with.  If you know of a better way to achieve this could you let me know?

Comment: Create it once as a class attribute, and it will still be accessible via instances via `self`.  You have not explained yet why it needs to change via `__init__`

Comment: I need it to change via init because I have to pass an instance of the larger class I want to interface with.  If I just constructed the object as classA = classB(...) it would have no knowledge of the larger class?

Comment: If you want to set it once for all instances of the class, have a separate `@classmethod` to set it, don't do it via `__init__`.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I see from your edit how to do that now.  I initially did that but then ran in to trouble since my classmethod didnt have a set so I couldnt change the class member! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the class attribute in `B.__init__`, just setting a new instance attribute - `B.ClassA` is still `''` (`None` would be a more sensible starting value, by the way).

The minimal fix is:

```
class B:

    ClassA = None

    def __init__(self, InstanceA):
        self.__class__.ClassA = InstanceA # or B.ClassA = ...
```

However, note that this changes the class attribute every time you create a new instance.

---

Based on your comments, something like this may be more helpful:

```
class B:

    ClassA = None

    @classmethod
    def set_class_attr(cls, instance):
        cls.ClassA = instance
```

Which you can then use like:

```
B.set_class_attr(A()) # set class attribute once

b = B() # don't need to pass in new A instances when creating B instances
b.ClassA. # ...
```

Depending on the behaviour you want, you can check in that classmethod whether the instance has already been set and e.g. `raise` an error if the user tries to reset it.

Comment: Subtle distinction: it may be a design decision whether `B.__init__` updates `B.ClassA` or `self.__class__.ClassA`.

Comment: Follow up question: When i use this I am calling it from inside the big object I wish to interface with so I say: B.set_class_attr(self), but this returns an error that set_class_attr() must be called with B as first argument

Comment: I could not replicate this behaviour; without seeing a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can't tell you what you're doing wrong. I suggest you open a new question, ensuring that you follow this checklist: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist